# On Macbook Pro with 2 HDMI monitors, is it possible to associate the USB-C/HDMI with a desktop/monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display, usb, hdmi

On Macbook Pro with 2 HDMI monitors via 2 USB-C/HDMI adapters. I have multiple desktop's on each display. The macbook itself always has the same desktops on, but my two HDMI monitors periodically/randomly switch their collective desktops.

- So all of the desktops on the right monitor will be displayed on the left, and vice versa.

This happens at times like, disconnecting and reconnecting to the monitors, not just randomly as you're typing. But it doesn't happen every time you disconnect.

Q: Is it possible to associate the USB-C/HDMI with a desktop, so that monitor 1 will always have the same content?

Note: Rearranging the order of displays in "Built-in Retina Display" is not a solution. As the adjoining monitor edges then change from 1L/2R to 2L/1R so mouse overs are the opposite side of monitors.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible. It is a bit of "hit and miss" when you have these situations. You can sometimes replug the cables and get the desired order, but it is not foolproof.